# How do I get this result?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

I am studying the following equation:

$$\dfrac{d^2}{dr^{*2}}R_k^l(r^*)=(V_{eff}-k^2)R_k^l(r^*)$$ where the potential is given by:

$$V_{eff}(r)=\left( 1-\dfrac{2M}{r} \right)\left( \dfrac{2M}{r^3} +\dfrac{l(l+1)}{r^2} \right)$$

and the coordinate $r^*$ is given by

$$r^*=r+2M \log(r/2M-1)$$

The constants $M$ and $l$ are both positive and $l$ can have only integer values. According to the text (Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler page 869 if needed) the function $R_k^L$ has the following asymptotic expansion:

$$R_k^l=\exp(ikr^*)+\Gamma \exp(-ikr^*) \quad r^*\rightarrow-\infty$$
$$R_k^l=T \exp(ikr^*) \quad r^*\rightarrow +\infty$$

And the coefficients $\Gamma$ and $T$ are given by

$$\Gamma=-1+2i\alpha M k$$
$$T=\dfrac{\beta}{(2l-1)!!} (2Mik)^{l+1}$$
for $k\ll1/M$. I do not understand how to calculate the coefficients. Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you forget to tell us what or where $k$ is?

Comment: @Stephane I forgot I am sorry it is a real parameter.

Comment: So since $V_{eff}$ goes to zero at $\pm \infty$, then it makes sense (heuristically) to think the solution will behave as a linear combination of $\exp(ikx)$ and $\exp(-ikx)$. To determine the precise linear combination, one needs some kind of condition, which should be in the book. Am I wrong?